# How to automatically change the nickname of your discord bot. (Javascript)(Discord.js)

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I want to set my discord bot's nickname every minute to change to some content from my API.

I read that you can only set nicknames on guild members but you need `message.guildmembers` for that. I don't want to send a message to be able to change the nickname, it has to happen automatically every minute.

I've been looking for solutions but can't find any.

Comment: You can use `Guild#me` to access the member object of the bot. However changing the nickname every minute is API spam and can lead to suspension

Comment: @Elitezen what would be the command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the server ID, you can fetch the guild when the bot is `ready` and add a `setInterval` to change the bot's nickname:

```js
client.on('ready', async () => {
  const GUILD_ID = '531138151659370517';
  const guild = await client.guilds.fetch(GUILD_ID);
  let i = 0;

  console.log('Bot is connected...');

  setInterval(() => {
    guild.me.setNickname(i++);
  }, 60 * 1000);

  // if you also want to set the nickname right after the bot is ready...
  guild.me.setNickname(i++);
});
```

Make sure you know about your rate limits: https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/rate-limits